# "Tabs and Windows" menu item is missing from the Environments section of Options

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I installed the most recent version of Visual Studio, so how can I fix this?

I tried to reinstall the application but the "Tabs and Windows" menu item is still missing from the "Environments" section of the options.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We really need some more detailed explanation. I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the gear icon where your tabs are and selecting "Options".  This will automatically open the options dialog and navigate it to the "Tab and Windows" section:

[image: image showing where the gear icon is with the options menu item]